# Break a variable-length list in two parts - one horizontally, and another vertical using only CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-position, absolute

I have a flat list, where I need to position some of the list items statically, and other list items absolutely (so that the content underneath is not affected).  However, the absolute list items need to not sit on top of one another and instead, arrange themselves stacked on top of one another.

I was able to replicate what I was hoping to do with `nth-child` selectors (see below) but that creates a "cap" on the number of `li` that it accounts for.  Click "Toggle More" to see the absolutely positioned children.

**Looking for a solution producing the same visual result, but flexible regarding number of `li`.  Cannot change HTML.  Would like CSS-only solution - no JS.**

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #afa;
}

li {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
li:nth-child(-n+3) {
  display: inline-block;
}

#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  min-width: 50%;
  background: #555;
  top: 100%;
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(5) {
  top: calc(100% + 30px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(6) {
  top: calc(100% + 60px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(7) {
  top: calc(100% + 90px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(8) {
  top: calc(100% + 120px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(9) {
  top: calc(100% + 150px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(10) {
  top: calc(100% + 180px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(11) {
  top: calc(100% + 210px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(12) {
  top: calc(100% + 240px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(13) {
  top: calc(100% + 270px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(14) {
  top: calc(100% + 300px);
}
#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(15) {
  top: calc(100% + 330px);
}
```

```html
<!-- http://codepen.io/allicarn/pen/vLqPNG -->

<div class="wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" id="show" />
  <label for="show">Toggle "More"</label>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <!-- CSS only accounts for up to 15 -->
  </ul>
</div>
<p>This is some content underneath the bar that should not be affected by the toggling open/close of the other children.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the effect that you want is more easily achieved floating the elements to right, and doing some trick on the first element to align thru the label , that is already floated

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #afa;
}

li {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
li:nth-child(-n+3) {
  display: inline-block;
}

#show:checked ~ ul li:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 0;
  min-width: 50%;
  background: #555;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  margin-left: -50%;     /* allow content to keep where it is */
}
```

```html
<!-- http://codepen.io/allicarn/pen/vLqPNG -->

<div class="wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" id="show" />
  <label for="show">Toggle "More"</label>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <!-- CSS only accounts for up to 15 -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div>Whatever content is under the bar - Whatever content is under the bar - Whatever content is under the bar</div>
```

Comment: This is great!  I need it to display like mine does - underneath the black bar, so the `margin-top: - 30px;` can be removed.  The only issue I have is now, if I have content underneath the bar, it flows around that menu dropdown, but I want it to be untouched by it's open/close state - that's why I went the `position:absolute` route.  Any suggestions on how I can achieve that with your approach?

Comment: Changed the top-margin trick to a margin-left trick :-)

Comment: This is awesome!  How does this work?

Comment: The elements have usually a width of 50%. If you set a margin on this, that would increase the space taken for the element (if it was positive) or decrease it (if it is negative). Since the margin is negative, and equal to the width, the space taken by the elements is 0